# on delphi/android how to draw a Jbitmap on a Canvas?

Tags: android, delphi, graphics, bitmap, firemonkey

Under delphi (and under firemonkey/android), What is the most fastest way to draw directly on a Tcanvas (of the form) a jBitmap ?

It's not the same question as **how to draw a TbitmapSurface on a Canvas**? :) here i want to draw one java object (jbitmap) to the delphi canvas or (i imagine) a jview or jsurfaceview representation of the delphi canvas

Comment: It is not a duplicate of question about Canvas...